# Django Oscar change URL pattern

Tags: django, django-oscar

I have setup a django-oscar project and I'm trying to configure the URLs. My goal is to change `/catalogue` to `/catalog`.

As per the documentation I've added `app.py` in `myproject/app.py`

**myproject/app.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from oscar import app


class MyShop(app.Shop):
    # Override get_urls method
    def get_urls(self):
        urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^catalog/', include(self.catalogue_app.urls)),
            # all the remaining URLs, removed for simplicity
            # ...
        ]
        return urlpatterns


application = MyShop()
```

**myproject/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from .app import application

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'', application.urls),

    url(r'^index/$',views.index, name = 'index'),
]
```

The project server runs without any error, but when I try `localhost:8000/catalog` I get

> NoReverseMatch at /catalog/ 'customer' is not a registered namespace.

The expected output is `localhost:8000/catalog` should return the catalogue page.

Comment: Are you overriding the templates and settings as well? The oscar default templates will reference many views  that may be missing in your custom url_patterns. See e.g. https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/defaults.py for a lot of view names that will have to be present if you do not customize the base template, the dashboard navigation, the home_page, the login_url, etc...

Comment: I did not override any templates nor did i fork any app yet. its just a default oscar installation. Is forking of catalogue app required as i am configuring catalogue urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on [c.grey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589748/django-oscar-cannot-change-urls/54590361#54590361) to specify how to **replace** instead of add the urls -

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from oscar import app


class MyShop(app.Shop):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyShop, self).get_urls()
        for index, u in enumerate(urls):
            if u.regex.pattern == r'^catalogue/':
                urls[index] = url(r'^catalog/', include(self.catalogue_app.urls))
                break
        return urls


application = MyShop()
```

Comment: What if I have to change complex Url pattern like checkout/shipping-address/ to something like checkout/billing-address/ ?

Comment: @abicrazieeee Then why not fork the `checkout` app & make the change in the `urls.py`? Doing it like this (as in my answer) is not really recommended for individual URLs.

Comment: So I need to fork checkout app, then create urls.py file and rewrite url pattern for checkout/billing-address/. Then should I (include) checkout urls in root urls.py? Could you please show me the exact code on how this is achieved as I don't find urls.py of default Oscar project on GitHub.

Comment: @abicrazieeee Basically, after forking the checkout app, you need to do the same (as shown in the answer) inside `checkout/app.py`'s `CheckoutApplication` class. Modify the `get_urls`, but with condition `u.regex.pattern == r'shipping-address/$'` & modification `urls[index] = url(r'billing-address/$', self.shipping_address_view.as_view(), name='shipping-address')`. You don't need to do anything else (no modifying `urls.py` anywhere).

Comment: It Says  AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

Comment: `from django.apps import AppConfig
from oscar import app
from django.conf.urls import url, include


class CheckoutConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'checkout'
    label = 'blackweb checkout'

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(CheckoutConfig, self).get_urls()
        for index, u in enumerate(urls):
            if u.regex.pattern == r'shipping-address/$':
                urls[index] = url(r'billing-address/$', self.shipping_address_view.as_view(), name='shipping-address')
                break
        return urls`

Comment: @abicrazieeee In that case you can just copy the [source code](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/src/oscar/apps/checkout/apps.py) for `apps.py` and paste it in your forked app with the relevant changes.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this

in app.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from oscar import app

class MyShop(app.Shop):
    # Override get_urls method
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = [
            url(r'^catalog/', include(self.catalogue_app.urls)),
            # all the remaining URLs, removed for simplicity
            # ...
        ]
        urls = urls + super(MyShop,self).get_urls()
        return urls


application = MyShop()
```

And in your urls.py
you can simply add this

```
from myproject.app import application as shop

 url(r'', shop.urls),
```

Hope it help for you

Comment: i get this error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'urls' referenced before assignment"
did you mean urls = url + super(MyShop,self).get_urls()?

Comment: It works!!! So basically i was missing rest of the urls in app.py. Is that correct?

Comment: hope it helps you,

Comment: i marked your answer as accept but this comes up-"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: so when i change /catalogue to /catalog the /catalogue url also still works. How do i disable that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the URLs, not reference them directly.

```
url(r'', include('application.urls')),
```

Comment: i've added url(r'', include(application.urls)), but the issue still persists. here's an error from server log "django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'customer' is not a registered namespace
"