# How to customize complex Url patterns in Django Oscar

Tags: python, django, e-commerce, django-urls, django-oscar

I have set up a Django-oscar project and I'm trying to configure the URLs. My goal is to change /checkout/shipping-address/ to /checkout/billing-address/

As per the documentation, I've added app.py in myproject/app.py

**myproject/app.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from oscar import app


class MyShop(app.Shop):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MyShop, self).get_urls()
        for index, u in enumerate(urls):
            if u.regex.pattern == r'^catalogue/':
                urls[index] = url(r'^product/', include(self.catalogue_app.urls))
            elif u.regex.pattern == r'^basket/':
                urls[index] = url(r'^cart/', include(self.basket_app.urls))
            elif u.regex.pattern == r'^checkout/shipping-address/':
                urls[index] = url(r'^checkout/billing-address/', include(self.checkout_app.urls))
                break
        return urls


application = MyShop()
```

**myproject/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from .app import application

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'', application.urls),

    url(r'^index/$',views.index, name = 'index'),
]
```

How can I change Checkout/shipping-address/ to checkout/billing-address/?

Comment: Related comment thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589748/django-oscar-change-url-pattern/54658972?noredirect=1#comment99425295_54658972