# Django-oscar : how to change the URL from root APP?

Tags: python, django-oscar

I'm developing an ecommerce website using **django-oscar 2.0.1**.

I would like to change the url to access catalogue (as described [here](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/howto/how_to_change_a_url.html#changing-the-root-app) in the documentation), but I always get this error :

```
**NoReverseMatch at / 'customer' is not a registered namespace.**.
```

I know I'm not the only one who get this error ([Django Oscar change URL pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54589748/django-oscar-change-url-pattern)) but the solution proposed is this post doesn't work for me (perhaps because django-oscar version was 1.6.5 at this time ?).

So, here is the step I followed based on django-oscar [documentation](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.1/internals/getting_started.html) :

- I created a new project in a python venv with django-oscar and all the dependencies.
- I forked the catalogue app

```
python manage.py oscar_fork_app catalogue forkedApps
```

- Edited the installed Apps

```py
    #'oscar.apps.catalogue',
    'forkedApps.catalogue.apps.CatalogueConfig',
    'oscar.apps.catalogue.reviews',
```

Here is the structure of the project :

```
project
    > forkedApps
        > catalogue
            . __init__.py
            . admin.py
            . apps.py
            . models.py
    > project
        . __init__.py
        . settings.py
        . urls.py
        . wsgi.py
```

- I tried to change catalogue base URL from /catalogue to /cata :

**Forked catalogue**

```py
    # forkedApps/catalogue/apps.py

    import oscar.apps.catalogue.apps as apps
    from oscar import config
    from django.conf.urls import url

    from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy

    class CatalogueConfig(apps.CatalogueConfig):
        name = 'forkedApps.catalogue'

    class MyShop(config.Shop):

        # Override get_urls method
        def get_urls(self):
            from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

            from oscar.views.decorators import login_forbidden
            urlpatterns = [
                url(r'^cata/', self.catalogue_app.urls),
                url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('catalogue:index')), name='home'),
                url(r'^basket/', self.basket_app.urls),
                #...all other urls
            ]
            return urlpatterns
```

**Project init**

```py
    #project/project/__init__.py

    default_app_config = 'forkedApps.catalogue.apps.MyShop'
```

**Project url**

```py
    #project/project/urls.py

    from django.apps import apps
    from django.urls import include, path
    from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        #path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
        path('', include(apps.get_app_config('catalogue').urls[0])),
        ### Does catalogue refers to my forked catalogue ? ###
    ]
```

And when I run the server **I got this error** :

> raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
>   django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'customer' is not a registered namespace

Do you have any idea about what I missed ?

**SOLUTION :**

I created an APP called 'oscar_url' (arbitrary name) and I added it to INSTALLED_APPS

**oscar_url init**

```py
    #project/oscar_url/__init__.py

    default_app_config = 'oscar_url.apps.MyShop'
```

**oscar_url apps**

```py
    #project/oscar_url/apps.py
    import oscar.config as apps
    from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    from django.conf.urls import url

    class MyShop(apps.Shop):
        name = 'oscar_url'

        def get_urls(self):
            from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

            from oscar.views.decorators import login_forbidden
            urlpatterns = [
                url(r'^cata/', self.catalogue_app.urls),
                url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('catalogue:index')), name='home'),
                url(r'^basket/', self.basket_app.urls),
                url(r'^checkout/', self.checkout_app.urls),
                #all others urls...
            ]
            return urlpatterns
```

And I modified the project urls :

**Project url**

```py
    #project/project/urls.py

    urlpatterns = [
        path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

        #path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar').urls[0])),
        path('', include(apps.get_app_config('oscar_url').urls[0])),
    ]
```

Comment: I used the same way as defined in the solution part, unfortunately, I was not able to change any view. Let say I want to override the dashboard view and add some custom stuff. Were you able to achieve this through the way you described above? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem, here how is the solution:
after forking apps, you apps.py in the forked application.Let say I have forked dashboard and it has apps.py automatically created with the following:
class DashboardConfig(apps.DashboardConfig):
     name = 'oscar_apps.dashboard'

import your vies inside  ready method and override ready and  get_urls methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things here:

1. You have defined a `MyShop` class, but you are not loading it anywhere. You need to include this app in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

   Note that in this context it probably doesn't make sense to have `MyShop` living inside your catalogue app - this shop app is for your entire project, not just for the catalogue.
2. In your project URLs, you need to load this new app's configuration instead of Oscar's:

   ```
   path('', include(apps.get_app_config('name_of_your_app').urls[0])),
   ```

   Where you would set `name = 'name_of_your_app'` in `MyShop`.

Comment: Where is the best place to store MyShop ? I tried to fork oscar (with oscar_fork_app oscar) but I get some errors when I try to replace it.

Comment: You can't fork the root app. Just store `MyShop` in the root of your project - e.g., `project/apps.py`.

Comment: I created a new app called 'django_url' for that. It works well without replacing oscar in installed apps.

Comment: Great. My original answer was slightly wrong (you still need `oscar` in `INSTALLED_APPS` otherwise other things will break) I've edited it slightly.